# Why are my values not posting to SQL Server DB but its not giving error either

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using code to post data that is submitted thru webform in php code to the database in a table.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach ($_POST as $arr) {
        echo $arr ."<br/>"; 
    } 
    $fund=$_POST['fund']; 
    $department=$_POST['department']; 
    $code_name=$_POST['code_name']; 
    $budget_year=$_POST['budget_year']; 
    $entry_date=$_POST['entry_date']; 
    $project_name=$_POST['project_name'];
    $item_desc=$_POST['item_desc']; 
    $amount=$_POST['amount']; 
    $detail=$_POST['detail']; 
    $PO=$_POST['PO']; 

    $query = "INSERT INTO Transaction (fund, department, code_name,
              budget_year, entry_date, project_name, item_desc, amount,
              detail, PO) VALUES ('$fund', '$department', '$code_name',
              '$budget_year', '$entry_date', '$project_name',
              '$item_desc', '$amount', '$detail', '$PO')"; 

    if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)) {
        die('An error has occurred.');
    } else {
        echo "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
    }

}

?>
```

I have it posting as the results right now and its not hitting the DB.  What am I doing wrong.  I have another page that I am posting just like this and it is hitting the DB with the same connection info.

[image]

Comment: Is it echoing the "Your information has been ..." line? Is it echoing nothing? What does the log say?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. What does the built query look like? Are all errors being shown? It's probably something invalidating the SQL and causing an error you are not being shown is my guess. Also look into how to securely run sql queries with user data being provided.

Comment: Its coming back with all of the credentials using the code included

    foreach ($_POST as $arr) {
 echo $arr ."<br/>"; 
 } 


General 
INFORMATION AND TECHNOLOGY SVCS - 41515
Computer Software - 5405
2020-2021
2018-05-31
One Solution 
fg
40.00
sdfdsf
jeff
Submit
An error has occurred.

Comment: Please, change "die('An error has occurred.');" to "die('An error has occurred. '.print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));" and show us error messages.

Comment: Thank you Zhorov that worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, change "die('An error has occurred.');" to "die('An error has occurred. '.print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));" and show us error messages.